# Баг Qt5, или его особенность?

Tags: c++, qt

```
simvol = 60; // т.е. имеется в виду код символа "<"

int simvol_email::left(QChar simvol)
{
    int x = 1;
    if (simvol > 64 and simvol < 91) x = 0;
    {
        x = 0; return x; // если ноль то символ допустим
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: А тут `if (simvol > 64 and simvol < 91) x = 0;` точка с запятой точно нужна?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Перепишем код более понятно.

```
int simvol_email::left(QChar simvol)
{
    int x = 1;

    if (simvol > 64 and simvol < 91)
        x = 0;

    // Здесь если символ от 65 до 90 включительно, `x` становится равным 0.

    {  // Новый блок, но т.к. в нем `x` не объявлена, то это та же `x`, что и вне блока...
        x = 0;
        // Теперь `x` БЕЗУСЛОВНО равно 0

        return x; // если ноль то символ допустим
        // И так же безусловно оно и возвращается...
    }

    return x;  // Сюда поток выполнения никогда не доберется.
}
```

Итак, не самый тупой компилятор оптимизирует эту функцию как

```
int simvol_email::left(QChar simvol)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Более детально пояснять, я думаю, не надо?

P.S. Сразу видно начинающего программиста знаете как? На любую свою ошибку тут же следует заявление "БАГ В ...!!!!". Да, баги в таком софте бывают. Но **гораздо реже**, чем вы думаете.

Принцип презумпции корректности компилятора и библиотек - вот одно из первых правил, которое следует усвоить. Компилятор и библиотеки безгрешны :), пока не **доказано** обратное.

Comment: Благодарю за разьяснение. Долго парился над такой ерундой, вывод нужно иногда отдыхать.